# Convert url to look like subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can i change my url `http://example.com/event_profile.php?event=5` to look like this

```
http://event.example.com/event-name
```

wheras the event name of event id 5 is `event-name`

or at least make it

```
http://event.example.com/5
```

is this possible with htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second is possible `http://event.example.com/5` because you are having clear value which can be rewritten. try with below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\d]+)$ event_profile.php?event=$1 [QSA,L]
```